how to compare a file word and a user input word in C as if in a log in data check
So i am creating this mini platform using C, and i am creaing the login section, where u get asked if you have an account or not, if you say yes then you get asked to enter your username, if your username is saved in the accounts.txt file, then you get asked to enter your password and so on.
and i used the strcmp function to compare the entered username and the file lines in a loop.
i spent a long time on this code and it is working without mistakes, but for some reason, even if the entered username is the exact same as the one in the line of the file, it says that they are not equal.
i know my explanation is pretty bad but i hope you got my idea.
in summary, why is the word in a file line, is not equal to a user input word, even if they are the exact same word, and do you have any other solutions for my code so that my idea work?
thank you for your time!
make sure to look into my code!
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fptr;
int main() {
    char a;
    char z = 'y';
    printf("Welcome! Do you have an account ?\n");
    printf("\tType \"y\" for yes or type \"n\" for no.\n");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    if(a == z){ usernamef(); }else { create(); }
}

void usernamef() {
    char username[5];
    char theString[5];
    fptr = fopen("accounts.txt", "r");
    printf("Enter your username\n");
    scanf("%s", username);
    while(fgets(theString, 5, fptr)) {
        if(0 = strcmp(username, theString)) {
            printf("yes");
        } else {printf("nope"); }
    }

// The code is not completed due to the problem i got, so i'm just testing things to try and find a solution for that problem.
}

void passwordf() {
    char passwordn[8];
    char password[] = "whatever";
    int cmp = strcmp(password, passwordn);
    printf("Enter your password\n");
    scanf("%s", passwordn);
     if(cmp==0){
        shade();
     } else {
         printf("password incorrect, try again or type r to create an account\n");
     }
}

void shade() {
    printf("Welcomeback shade! i hope you are having a good day :)\n");
}

void create(){
    char username[10];
    char password[10];
    printf("Create an account to continue\n");
    printf("Make sure to follow this instructions\n");
    printf("\t1. make sure the username and the password are shorter than 10 characters.\n");
    printf("\t2. make sure it's one word, don't use spaces\n");
    printf("\t3. Do not use special characters.\n");
    printf("Now enter the username:");
    scanf("%s", username);
    fptr = fopen("accounts.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", username);
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("Enter the password\n");
    scanf("%s", password);
    fptr = fopen("accounts.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", password);
    fclose(fptr);
    shade();
}


So as i explained everything above, i tried to compare the word written in the file (no spaces used) with a user input name, and even tho it is the exact same word, it says it's not in the result (i used the the function strcmp and i added it's library)

The code you show will result in an error, because you attempt to assign something to the integer value 0. There are some other problems as well, like when you try to compare two strings before you get the input from one of them; Having global variables which is a bad habit; Calling functions that haven't been declared yet; Different sizes in different function for input from user and file; And more.

You should also check the return value from the functions you use, like scanf. Using scanf like you do is also risky since it may write out of bounds. "make sure the username and the password are shorter than 10 characters" leaves it up the the user to not cause undefined behavior. Not good. Passwords (and usernames) may not contain whitespaces in your system either, which seems odd.

Before you bring a question to Stack Overflow, (a) Debug it yourself. Examine the strings at the point of comparison to see exactly what is being compared to what. You can do this with a debugger or simply by printing each string, with care to explicitly display all characters in the string, including spaces, tabs, and newlines. (b) You should reduce the problem to just code that has the problem, usually eliminating all the scanf and other input in the program by replacing it with hard-coded data, making a [mre]. (c) You should test that the reduced example compiles.

Not only will this have undefined behaviour if I go over 9 bytes for my username, what if I enter "abcde" for my username? it is valid in create but impossible to read in usernamef, thus corrupting all "accounts.txt". Suggest a struct and rules for serializing/deserializing that struct to a (text) file.

@Alaa, Is if(0 = strcmp(username, theString)) { the true code that you ran?

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the problem. Without the proper input, it may be impossible for other people to reproduce the problem. Your code is referring to a file named accounts.txt, but you did not specify the exact content of the file.

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem. Your posted code does not reproduce the described problem, because it does not compile without errors.

If you insist on using scanf you should at least limit the input size to avoid buffer overflow: scanf("%4s", username); This will only read up to 4 characters into your buffer. And you should ask yourself if it is a good idea to have arrays for username that have different size in each function.


Do not use scanf
Remove trailing and leading whitespace
if(0 = strcmp(username, theString)) - you assign 0 with value you need to use ==


thank you guys for all the help, info and suggestions, you have been a huge help and motive to keep working on this, i'll make sure to fix it according to your notes, see you in another project or idea!
